# Firebase Android App read from database onDataChange not called

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I got a problem with getting data from my firebase database.
The concrete problem is, that the `onDataChange` method (`ValueEventlistener`) isn't called.

Application proceed:

```
DatabaseConnectionManager()
readFromDatabase()
getEventFormulaGet()
```

`eventFormulaGet` is empty, because `onDataChange` isn't called....

Code:

```
package bbcag.ch.miivent_luca;

    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


    public class DatabaseConnectionManager implements ValueEventListener {
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private EventFormula eventFormulaSend;
    private EventFormula eventFormulaGet;

    public DatabaseConnectionManager() {
        createConnectionToDatabase();
    }

    public void createConnectionToDatabase() {

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getReference();

    }

    public void readFromDatabase() {
        databaseReference.child("events").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(this);
    }

    public void deleteFromDatabase() {

    }

    public void setEventFormula(EventFormula eventFormula) {
        this.eventFormulaSend = eventFormula;
    }

    public void sendFormulaToDatabase() {
        databaseReference.child("events").child(eventFormulaSend.getEventTitle()).setValue(eventFormulaSend);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        eventFormulaGet = dataSnapshot.getValue(EventFormula.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }

    public EventFormula getEventFormulaGet() {
        return eventFormulaGet;
    }

}
```

Comment: onDataChange() is called async. Put a Log statement inside onDataChange   , check and post result.

Comment: onDataChange isnt (neither async nor manual) called so the Log statement inside onDataChange isnt executed either (correct me if i made english mistakes)

Comment: why don't you print the onCanceled exception to check what's going on